# File path to a resource file inside .war folder

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, war, resteasy

I have to read records from a text file in my REST service method by accessing it by its relative path.

The service has been deployed to JBoss Application Server 7.1.1.

Where should I place the file inside the JBoss directory structure
and what would be the best way of accessing resources in this type of a scenario.

I tried placing the file in the root of the war directory which returned `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Accessing it through the absolute path worked fine.

Comment: The text file is packaged in the war file ?

Comment: No, I manually copied the file to the location. I tried adding the file to the project root directory, that didn't work too @SaifAsif

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the file to the root of the project and then do the following

```
// Use resourceAsStream of the classLoader to load the file
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myFile.properties");

// optionally wrap it with a bufferedReader if the file is large
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Or if the path of the file is never going to change, you can use absolute paths as follows

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/home/user/file/myFile.properties");
```

Comment: Accessing the file through the absolute path worked. 
First method returned with a java.lang.NullPointerException.  I'm looking for a solution on accessing the file inside the JBoss folder structure.